# Find the equation of the cylinder whose two directions are given.

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

> The radial directions of a cylinder is given by
>   $$
> \begin{array}
>  wx^2+y^2=5^2, \\ z=0 .
> \end{array}
> $$ and axial directions of a cylinder is
>   $$\vec a=(5,3,2)$$ respectively. Find the equation of the cylinder.

Because of the lockdown due to the pandemic, I was not able to attend the lessons. Therefore, I'm having trouble solving this kind of exercises. I would kindly ask you to give me a solution and help me understand (so that I would be able to solve the rest problems myself). I've gained some background on cylinders, but that seems not to be sufficient to solve this.

Comment: You really shouldn’t [delete a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3687752/265466) and then repost it verbatim less than half a day later just because it hasn’t gotten an answer and you’re in some sort of hurry. Things happen (or not) here at their own pace; your deadlines or looming exams aren’t really a consideration. I was in the process of posting an answer to the original question when you deleted it, so now I’ll spend my time on other things instead.

Comment: @amd I'm so sorry for that! Yeah you are right the deadlines are coming and stress forced me to repost. But yeah I agree with you that was a wrong decision. Sorry. Thanks for your try to answer, you are totally right not to re-write the answer wasting your time if you wish.

Comment: I’ll give you the two hints for methods that I was going to expand on: (1) Use the directrix/generatrix definition of a general cylinder to write a set of parametric equations for it, then eliminate the parameters. (2) Find a transformation that will warp the axis of a right circular cylinder to be parallel to $\vec a$ instead and apply that transformation to its equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At height $z$ the horizontal section of the cylinder is a circle, with center 
$\big({5\over2}z,{3\over2}z,z\big)$ and radius $5$. Hence the equation 
of the cylinder is:
$$
\left(x-{5\over2}z\right)^2+\left(y-{3\over2}z\right)^2=5^2
$$

Comment: In my book, it's written that the equation of the cylinder is the same as its directrix (circle in this case) if the generatrices of the cylinder are parallel to $z$-axis. So could we take the answer like yours? But I think the generatrices are not parallel to $z$-axis in this case... Or did I got something wrong?

Comment: My equation is NOT the same as the generatrix.

Comment: @VIVID See the resulting graph with GeoGebra: https://www.geogebra.org/classic/mbmuwg5q

Comment: Ok, but why did you divide the vector by 2. I know that it does not change the direction, but if you wouldn't divide then the equation would of the form $$(x-5z)^2+(y-3z)^2=5^2$$

Comment: Oh thanks for the drawing, that's cool!

Comment: Read carefully what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: I think I fully got the solution now, and it's beautiful! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Calling $p = (x,y,z)$ and giving

$$
L\to p = p_0 +\lambda\vec a\\
C\to \left(p_0\cdot p_0\right)_{z=0} = r^2\\
$$

$C$ is the projection along the $\vec a$ direction onto the plane $z=0$ of the ellipsoid

$$
E\to x^2+y^2+c_{33}z^2+c_{13} x z+c_{23}yz=c_0\Rightarrow p_0\cdot M\cdot p_0=c_0
$$

so $L\cap E$ is given by

$$
(p-\lambda\vec a)\cdot M\cdot(p-\lambda\vec a) = c_0
$$

or

$$
\lambda^2\vec a\cdot M\cdot\vec a -2\lambda p\cdot M\vec a+p\cdot M\cdot p = c_0
$$

solving for $\lambda$ we have

$$
\lambda = p\cdot M\vec a\pm \sqrt{\left( p\cdot M\vec a\right)^2-(\vec a\cdot M\cdot\vec a)(p\cdot M\cdot p-c_0)}
$$

but we need tangency between $E$ and $L$ hence

$$
\left( p\cdot M\vec a\right)^2-(\vec a\cdot M\cdot\vec a)(p\cdot M\cdot p-c_0)=0
$$

This is the cylinder equation. Additionally we know that for $z=0$ the intersection of $E$ with the plane $z=0$ is $C$ so equating coefficients

$$
\left(\left( p\cdot M\vec a\right)^2-(\vec a\cdot M\cdot\vec a)(p\cdot M\cdot p-c_0)\right)_{z=0}\equiv x^2+y^2-r^2
$$

we get

$$
c_0 = 25,\ c_{13} = -5,\ c_{33} = \frac{33}{4}
$$

so the cylinder equation is

$$
x^2-5 x z+y^2-3 y z+\frac{17 z^2}{2}-25=0
$$

Follows an illustration.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is your answer the same as the answer by @Aretino ? I think they are not... Your answer is $$\left(x-{5\over2}z\right)^2+\left(y-{3\over2}z\right)^2-\frac{1}{16}z^2=5^2$$ Why is this?

Comment: An error in the computation of $c_{33}$ now fixed.